# Make text box editable and save it

Tags: javascript, html

I am wanting to make a text box on a webpage that anyone can edit and also save. So when they refresh the page their text is still there.

Here is the simple code I have so far. I can edit it just haven't figured out how to save it.

```html
<div id="example-one" contenteditable="true">
<style scoped>
  #example-one { margin-bottom: 10px; }
  [contenteditable="true"] { padding: 10px; outline: 2px dashed #CCC; }
  [contenteditable="true"]:hover { outline: 2px dashed #0090D2; }
</style>
<p>Save Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Look into cookies, localStorage, a database etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
<div id="example-one" contenteditable="true">

</div>
<p id="save">Save Text</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener('click', function(el) {
    localStorage.setItem("text", document.getElementById('example-one').innerHTML);
});

window.onload = function() {
    var text = localStorage.getItem("text");
    document.getElementById('example-one').innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed!!